# netctl start asks for root password

Tags: linux, networking, passwords

Every time I do `netctl start Newton` (`Newton` is the name of my wifi network's profile) I get this message:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or other units.
Authenticating as: root
Password:
```

If I type the wrong password I get the message:

```
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start netctl@Newton.service: Access denied
```

This isn't actually a problem for me because I know my root password, but it strikes me that if I didn't, I wouldn't be able to connect to the internet and that's not right. I'm a sudoer so I should be able to use my own password to connect to the network, but it asks for root's.

How do I make it stop asking for the root password?

Comment: Phew, it's commom for others, it's not a virus!

Answer (score 9):

So the reason I was being asked for the root password was because I wasn't running the command with sudo. If I do that it won't ask for a password.

Comment: Yes, `netctl` aliased with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Try in `visudo`

```
user host= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/netctl
```

Use absolute path !

Comment: So you mean I need to add that line to the sudoers file? I tried that and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: When I removed the space before `NOPASSWD` the message changed to `Failed to start netctl@Newton.service: Interactive authentication required.`

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to remove PolicyKit,

```
sudo apt-get remove libpolkit-agent-1-0
```

ought to make this easier.